# Create Genymotion Emulator from Command Line

Tags: android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

i'm able to start existing genymotion emulator on a headless server with these commands:

1. Search for emulator name by using `VBoxManage list vms`
2. Start the genymotion player by using `DISPLAY=:99 player --vm-name "emulatorname"`

note: i'm using Xvfb as display on port 99, that's why i use prefix `DISPLAY=:99`

but how if i want to create a new emulator from scratch? is it possible from command line / headless mode on Genymotion?
i'm using genymotion personal edition here